# Can not access Language Resource

Tags: c#, visual-studio

I am trying to convert string to different language, based on current culture.

Following this tutorial:

https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/9209/Generating-String-Resource-Accessors-for-NET

Nevertheless, I receive the following error:

> Could not find any resources appropriate for the specified culture or the neutral culture.  Make sure "Servicios.MultiLenguaje.resources" was correctly embedded or linked into assembly

This is my project structure:

[image]

Also, my res files are already configured like this:

[image]

Finally my code to access the resource is:

```
ResourceManager rm = new ResourceManager("Servicios.MultiLenguaje",
    Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly());
```

Comment: I would put C# as the first word in the title (or remove C# from the title); when I read the title-only I thought it was about the C# language itself....

Comment: I think I do not have the privilege to do that.

Comment: What Assembly is your *access the resource* code in?  I say this because if it's not in `Servicios` then the resources don't exist.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you also need a 'default' resource file with no culture code for it to fall back to if the localised version does not exist: `MultiLenguaje.resx`.

Also try:

```
var rm = new ResourceManager("Servicios.MultiLenguaje", typeof(x).Assembly);
```

Where `x` is any class *in the same project* as the resource files. If you're using `GetExecutingAssembly()`, it might be that the executing assembly is a different one to the one that contains the resource files.

Comment: Modified the answer to suggest a potential other issue.

Comment: Can you right-click on the project and check the Default namespace in the properties? Same error or different error?

Comment: I have checked the default namespace and It was Incorrect. I am Assuming, at some point the project name was changed and that produced the error.Works now. Thanks Steve!

Answer (score -1):

Visual studio requires you to download packages seperately. I hope you have tried downloading the C# package. If not, please download the package through Visual Studio Installer > Modify and so on

Comment: Maybe It is confusing because of the title, but the language resources is what I can not access.